# Widgets not showing up when using multiple frames Tkinter.py

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which switches between two Tkinter frames on the button press but none of the widgets show up.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
from settings import *
from tkinter import *




def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

def mainFunc():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry(screenSize)


    f1 = Frame(root)
    f2 = Frame(root)

    f1.place(x=610, y=370)
    f2.place(x=610, y=370)

    Button(f1, text='Go to frame 2', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).place(x=50, y=150)
    Label(f1, text='FRAME 1').place(x=50, y=50)




    Label(f2, text='FRAME 2').place(x=50, y=50)
    Button(f2, text='Go to frame 1', command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).place(x=50, y=150)


    raise_frame(f1)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunc()
```

Any help is appreciated. Updated the code.

Comment: You even didn't use layout manager to put your frame in your window.

Comment: I'm new tkinter so I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Like `f1.place(xxxx)` and `f2.place(xxx)`.

Comment: I added `f1.place(x=610, y=370)` and `f2.place(x=610, y=370)` to my code and it still does't work,

Comment: The size of the frames are zero because the widgets inside frames are layout using `place()`.  Also what is `screenSize`? You may put the frames outside the viewable area.

Comment: `screenSize = '1020x740+50+50'`

Comment: Also what do you mean they aren't in the viewable area?

Comment: If the screenSize is small, for example 400x300, putting the frames at (510,370) will make them out of the viewable area.  BTW, you need to specify the size of the  frames.

Comment: The size is 1020x740

Comment: Update the code with what you have tried/changed.

Comment: It's been updated

Comment: As I said, you need to specify the size of the frames.  Try `f1.place(..., relwidth=1, relheight=1)`.  Same for `f2`.

Comment: `f1 = Frame(root, width = 1040, height = 540)` Worked